# Hide values in combobox with a relationship

Tags: combobox, dynamics-ax-2012, relation

I have a form with a combobox to select a campaign (SalesQuotationTable with a relation to the campaign table), each campaign has its own status: Planned, in Progress or Closed.

I don't want to show the campaigns with the status: Closed in the combobox, I have tried to add an extra element to the relationship:

A relatied field fixed with the value: 0 and RelatiedField: CampaignClosed.

I still can see the closed campaigns in the drop down menu, but when I click the closed campaign AX2012 shows the error:

```
The value '00002' in field 'Campaign ID' is not found in the related table 'Campaigns'.
```

How can i accomplish to hide the closed campaign from the combobox?

Comment: Could you tell us more about the combobox? Is it unbound? If yes, how does the code of the lookup method look like? If no, on what table and field is it based and how does that table or field relate to quotations and campaigns?

Comment: Have you written any custom code to populate combo box list? If the combo box field lookup is populated by edt relation then you may need to override the lookup in form level. Found one blog on creating a customised lookup. This may help you. http://ashokkancheti.blogspot.com/2014/03/x-code-to-create-customized-lookup-on.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that a tree lookup was built to lookup the data, I have edited the code to filter the status.